# java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Lance Dean\Desktop\Java\End.jpg (Access is Denied)

Tags: java

When i run the code, the file shows up and it disappears and this error shows up. It disappears in the middle of the execution of the code.[image: The error shows up]

The Java folder only has Sample.jpg, ColorGet.java and ColorGet.class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.lang.*;

public class ColorGet{
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    BufferedImage img = null;
    File f = null;
    File m = null;
    int c = 0;
    try{
      f = new File("C:\\Users\\Lance Dean\\Desktop\\Java\\Sample.jpg");
      img = ImageIO.read(f);
    }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    for (int i=0; i < width;i++){
        for (int j=0; j < height;j++){
            int p = img.getRGB(i,j);
            int r = (p>>16) & 0xff;
            int g = (p>>8) & 0xff;
            int b = p & 0xff;
            c++;
            System.out.println(c);
            int a = 4 * (int)(Math.floor(255/4));
            int x = 4 * (int)(Math.floor((double)(r/4)));
            int y = 4 * (int)(Math.floor((double)(g/4)));
            int z = 4 * (int)(Math.floor((double)(b/4)));
            p = (a<<24) | (x<<16) | (y<<8) | z;
            img.setRGB(i, j, p);
            try{
                m = new File("C:\\Users\\Lance Dean\\Desktop\\Java\\End.jpg");
                if (!m.canRead()){
                    m.setReadable(true);
                }
                ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", m);
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What user are you running as? Does the folder `C:\\Users\\Lance Dean\\Desktop\\Java` exist? What do you mean by _"the file shows up and it disappears"_?  How do you see this?  Why do you `setReadable()` just before ***writing*** to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of IO operations in your code. Let's say image is 400x300, then you have opened and write the file for 12k times. As IO ops might be blocking, hence you might face access denied issue if the file is blocked by previous operation. It's better to do one write only at the end.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    File f = null;
    File m = null;
    int c = 0;
    try {
        f = new File("C:\\Users\\Lance Dean\\Desktop\\Java\\Sample.jpg");
        img = ImageIO.read(f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int p = img.getRGB(i, j);
            int r = (p >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g = (p >> 8) & 0xff;
            int b = p & 0xff;
            c++;
            System.out.println(c);
            int a = 4 * (int) (Math.floor(255 / 4));
            int x = 4 * (int) (Math.floor((double) (r / 4)));
            int y = 4 * (int) (Math.floor((double) (g / 4)));
            int z = 4 * (int) (Math.floor((double) (b / 4)));
            p = (a << 24) | (x << 16) | (y << 8) | z;
            img.setRGB(i, j, p);
        }
    }
    try {
        m = new File("C:\\Users\\Lance Dean\\Desktop\\Java\\End.jpg");
        if (!m.canRead()) {
            m.setReadable(true);
        }
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", m);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```